# How do I compare two IloNumArrays in Cplex C++ API?

Tags: c++, arrays, constraints, cplex

I want to add constraints to my Cplex model, that ensures that a bunch of arrays are pairwise different. That is, at least one entry should differ in the two.

(To clarify: The IloNumVarArray h represents an n x m matrix and the constraints should ensure that no two rows are identical)

My code below has two errors (at least) that I can't seem to solve:
- First, there is 'no suitable conversion function from IloNumVar to IloNum',
- Second, it is not allowed to use the != operator to compare IloNumArrays.

```
IloNumVarArray h(env, n*m);
IloNumArray temp1(env, m);
IloNumArray temp2(env, m);
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    temp1.clear();
    temp2.clear();
    for (int k = 0; k < n - i; k++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            temp1[j] = h[j + i * m];
            temp2[j] = h[j + (i + k) * m];
        }
    model.add(temp1 != temp2);
}
```

So how can I change temp1 and temp2 such that it is possible to copy from h, and compare the two?
(or do it completely different)
I am quite new to Cplex and I would appreciate any help/suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use logical constraints.

Let me give you an example in OPL CPLEX that you could adapt to C++

```
int n=3;
int m=2;

range N=1..n;
range M=1..m;

float epsilon=0.0001;

dvar float temp1[N][M] in 0..10;
dvar float temp2[N][M] in 0..10;

minimize sum(i in N,j in M) (temp1[i][j]+temp2[i][j]);
subject to
{
  // at least for one (i,j) the 2 arrays are different
  1<=sum(i in N,j in M) (abs(temp1[i][j]-temp2[i][j])>=epsilon);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Like this I don't even need the temp arrays :)